# How can I check if a type is a specialization of std::bitset?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I'm struggling to check at compile time if type is std::bitset or not.

I would like to to something like:

```
is_bitset<std::bitset<2>>::value; // should evaluate to true
is_bitset<int>::value; // should evaluate to false
```

I think this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61252904/check-if-template-type-is-any-instantiation-of-stdarray) is pointing in the right direction, but for some reason I can't manage to make it workd with std::bitset.

What's the best way to do this with C++14?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: when you have problems with code you should post a [mcve] of the code with the problem. The answer is more or less just repeating what is already in the other anwer, but what is the problem in your code, nobody knows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is very similar to the answer in the link you posted:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_bitset : std::false_type {};

template<std::size_t N>
struct is_bitset<std::bitset<N>> : std::true_type {};

static_assert(is_bitset<std::bitset<2>>::value); // should evaluate to true
static_assert(!is_bitset<int>::value); // should evaluate to false
```

Note that the primary template takes a type, while the specialization for `bitset` takes a non-type parameter.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/_x2Cba).

Comment: By the way, you edited your question for a c++14 solution. I believe this will work all the way back to c++11 actually.